# ¿Cómo generar un boxplot a partir de sus parámetros?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

Es muy simple generar un boxplot a partir de una muestra de datos, por ejemplo para ver como se distribuyen la millas por galón según la cantidad de cilindros, en la clásica `mtcars`:

```
mtcars %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=factor(cyl), y=mpg, fill=factor(cyl))) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

---

El resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero, si no tenemos la muestra de datos, sino únicamente los parámetros básicos que definen el "boxplot", es decir, la mediana y los cuartiles, ¿es posible realizar esta gráfica? ¿cómo sería?

Ejemplo de datos resumen:

```
mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  summarize(
       y0 = min(mpg),
       y25 = quantile(mpg, 0.25),
       y50 = median(mpg),
       y75 = quantile(mpg, 0.75),
       y100 = max(mpg)
  ) -> resumen

resumen

# A tibble: 3 x 6
    cyl    y0   y25   y50   y75  y100
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  21.4  22.8  26    30.4  33.9
2     6  17.8  18.6  19.7  21    21.4
3     8  10.4  14.4  15.2  16.2  19.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sí, es perfectamente posible con los sumarios que tienes.

Si aún no tienes los datos en un data.frame el primer paso es crear la estructura de datos para posteriormente hacer el gráfico. Necesitas:

- `x` = El identificador de grupo, la categoría a la que pertenecen las medidas.

Se podría hacer un boxplot con una sola variable, pero en general estos gráficos se utilizan para comparar la distribución de una variable condicional a un factor o variable categórica.

- `mediana` = la mediana de cada categoría de `x`
- `q1` = el cuartil 1, controla la ubicación de la parte inferior de la caja
- `q3` = el cuartil 3, controla la ubicación de la parte superior de la caja

Los extremos de la distribución (bigotes) los obtienes a partir de estos datos.
Por la documentación de `geom_boxplot()` el máximo del bigote está 1.5IQR arriba de  la mediana y el mínimo 1.5IQR debajo. El IQR (rango intercuartil) es `q3-q1`.

```
tibble(
  x = c("primero", "segundo", "tercero"),
  mediana = c(3, 4, 5),
  q1 = c(2, 3, 4), 
  q3 = c(4, 5, 6),
  distancia = (1.5*(q3-q1)), 
  minbigote = mediana - distancia, 
  maxbigote = mediana + distancia -> datos_para_box
```

Luego tienes que mapear, uno a uno, estos valores a la llamada de `geom_boxplot()` y usar `stat = "identity"` para impedir que la función trate de calcular por sí sola estos estadísticos.

```
ggplot(data = datos_para_box) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = x, 
                   middle = mediana, 
                   lower = q1, 
                   upper = q3, 
                   ymin = minbigote, 
                   ymax = maxbigote, 
                   group = x), 
               stat = "identity")
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si prefieres que las cajas queden horizontales deberías mapear `y` en lugar de `x` y luego `xlower`, `xupper`, `xmin` y `xmax`. Por suerte los errores que da `geom_boxplot()` son bastante informativos sobre los parámetros que hacen falta.

## Digresión extensa sobre la extensión de los bigotes (whiskers)

En Exploratory Data Analysis de John Tukey (1977) se presentan dos versión del boxplot, una en la que los bigotes definen el rango de la variable medida (los percentiles 1 y 100) y otro en el que presentan a los "innermost identified values" (p.40) y, más allá de los bigotes, se presentan a los valores outliers como puntos. Por esta característica Tukey recomienda usar este método por encima del de rango. Sin embargo no define como se obtienen esos "innermost identified values". Hay varias formas de hacerlo.

En R `base` y `ggplot` tienen métodos de cálculo diferentes. Según la ayuda de `geom_boxplot()` por defecto esta "zona interior" se define como Q2 +- 1.5*IQR, es decir, 1.5 veces el rango intercuartil +- la mediana. Es el método de cálculo más común.

Sin embargo `boxplot.stats` indica que el cálculo es   Q2 +- 1.58*IQR/ sqrt(n). Es decir, divide 1.58*IQR entre la raíz cuadrada de n. Esta segunda versión aproxima mejor al error estándar de una distribución normal e indican algo parecido a un intervalo de confianza del 95%. Esto suena muy bien, excepto que si los datos no provienen de una distribución normal esos errores no son nada robustos.

La elección de uno u otro depende de los objetivos de la investigación y de nuestros supuestos distribucionales (asumir o no distribución normal subyacente). En lo personal me gusta la estadística no paramétrica... no paramétrica. No le encuentro el caso a usar la teoría normal para un gráfico que usamos, muchas veces, para explorar distribuciones sesgadas, asimétricas y sobredispersas.

Answer (score 1):

Es posible, el boxplot es un gráfico muy básico (y tremendamente útil), básico, por que requiere en principio solo 5 parámetros, la mediana, que es la línea mas gruesa dentro de la caja, los cuartiles 1, 2 (Mediana) y 3 que son los límites de la "caja" y las lineas representan lo valores extremos no atípicos. Adicionalmente, se le suele agregar información de los "outliers" o valores "atípicos", obviamente estos últimos no se pueden reproducir de forma parámetrica, necesitamos los datos sin embargo, si obviamos esto, el `geom_boxplot()` además de graficar a partir de la muestra, es capaz de hacerlo a partir de los parámetros mencionados.

Los datos:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 6
    cyl    y0   y25   y50   y75  y100
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     4  21.4  22.8  26    30.4  33.9
2     6  17.8  18.6  19.7  21    21.4
3     8  10.4  14.4  15.2  16.2  19.2
```

La gráfica:

```
resumen %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_boxplot(aes(x = factor(cyl),
                   fill = factor(cyl),
                   ymin = y0, 
                   lower = y25, 
                   middle = y50, 
                   upper = y75, 
                   ymax = y100),
               stat = "identity") +
  ylab("mpg")
```

---

El Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eventualmente, también funciona así con los gráficos de R base, puedes consultar esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56487589/how-to-create-a-boxplot-with-customized-quantiles-in-r) con varios ejemplos al respecto

Comment: Eliminé una respuesta duplicada y la copié (con cambios) aquí. La parte R es muy similar a tu respuesta, sin embargo señalo una pequeña diferencia al momento de calcular el largo de los bigotes y una pequeña discusión sobre el tema.

Comment: Interesante @mpaladino, no conocía las diferencias entre ggplot y r base.